# Select only unique records from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that logs downloads by IP, version and platform. Looking at the table manually I see a lot of duplicates where all 3 of those values are the same. (user is probably just impatient) I'd like to use a SELECT statement that filters out the duplicates and only returns one of the entries if all 3 of those values are the same. Even more advanced, if possible, I also have a date/time field that uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Would be nice if I could include duplicates if they are from different days, but not different times. So I can see if the same user is downloading again on a different day.

I'm mainly just trying to get statistics on how many unique people download each version each day. The structure of the DB table is simple...

key (AUTO_INCREMENT), date (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), ip, user_agent, platform, version

The software has a Windows and Mac version (platform) and I offer both the current version and a few distinct past versions that were before major changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by the fields you want to exclude from being duplicated, like

```
SELECT ip, platform, version, COUNT(*) AS number_of_tries, max(download_date) AS last_download_date 
FROM downloads
GROUP BY ip, platform, version, DATE(download_date)
```

It would then be relatively easy to do some more advanced filtering over the result grouping by day, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?  It returns the first record on each date for the `ip`/`platform`/`version` combination:

```
select t.*
from <tablename> t
where t.datetime = (select min(t2.datetime)
                    from <tablename> t2
                    where t2.ip = t.ip and
                          t2.platform = t.platform and
                          t2.version = t.version and
                          date(t2.datetime) = date(t.datetime)
                   );
```

Comment: I have to test it, but this seems like exactly what I want

Comment: OK sorry for the basic question but I can't figure out what to actually use for t and t2. The table name is 'downloads'. I replaced all instances of 't' with 'downloads' but I'm not sure what to do with t2. I tried just leaving it as t2 but I get 0 rows.

SQL is not really my forte. I use it occasionally, but I'm mainly a C/C++ developer so I never do more then basic SELECT/INSERT type stuff.

Answer (score 0):

mysql 8.0+ version you can use `row_number()`

```
select * from (select *,
row_number()over(partition by ip,platform,date(datetime) order by datetime) rn
       from table_name 
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Looks like my host is using 5.7. Is there a similar way to do this in lower versions?

Comment: @Dan no its available from 8 in mysql